# mail command doesn't work

Tags: email, debian-squeeze

When I try this on Debian Squeeze

```
date |mail -s "mail test " myUser
```

with mail command get

```
No mail for myUser
```

Comment: it's debian, so I would presume you have exim running. what is in the mail log at /var/log/exim4/main?

Answer (score 3):

default the mail command isn't used to send mail but to read it.

on debian box install xmail to be able to send mail:

```
  aptitude install xmail
```

this will allow you to send mail using your command

```
 date |mail -s "mail test " myUser
```